# Coding in dojo, 1.got error owner document null or not an object, 2. button label not updating after changing

Tags: javascript, dojo

1. I created a Label like this

   ```
   <label id="unit">Unit</label>
   ```

I'm trying to change the label programatically, writing the code,

```
dojo.place('<label>'+grid.getItem(itr-1).unit+'</label>', dojo.byId('unit'), 'replace');
```

But IE7 is throwing error,     ownerDocument is null or not an object.

Where as if I perform the operation in dojo.addOnload functon it is working perfectly fine.

2 . I tried changing the label of the button like

```
    saveButton.label="Modify";
```

When i gave , alert(saveButton.label); the new value is shown,
but not updationg on screen.

Please provide solutions for above two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not `saveButton.label="Modify"`  its `saveButton.innerHTML`